# wampserver mysql MySQL server's socket is not correctly configured

Tags: mysql, apache, wampserver

I'm pulling my hair out with my mysql server.

I have wampserver installed, I have been working away on this with it all working fine for ages, my localhost site accessing my database etc etc.

I recently had to install IIS to manage a remote server, their was an initial conflict of ports but I resolved this and all seemed to be working well.

I've logged onto my PC after being away from it (we development) for a couple of weeks and I'm unable to get my site to connect to the mysql server.

I've carried out the following:
disabled IIS from the windows components
re-installed the latest version of wampserver
can connect to the mysql console
can connect to the mysql server through heidisql (mysql client)
deleted and recovered the data itself
re-booted loads of times

My php connect scripts arent working (but the same scripts do on my laptop (via wampserver installed there not across a network)

I tried starting phpmyadmin from the wampserver menu and it comes up with the error 2002 socket not configured correctly

Can anyone point me in the right direction please

Thank you

edit: I found another post and suggested run netstat. I've done this and found two entries for port 3306. So, I just tried changing my.ini to port 3307 in case there are two versions? is this possible?

Restarted mysql server but now heidi sql or mysql console can't connect. heidi changed port to connect on 3306 and did connect

I'm running around in circles here

Thanks

Comment: I must admit I didn't understand whether you're doing this on your home PC which runs Windows or if you're using your home PC to manage some kind of remote server. Can you clarify your question and explain in detail what does what, what operating systems are involved etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm running on a home pc with windows 7 64bit. The server is an apache server installed on the PC.

I've managed to resolve by removing wampserver again and installing xampp. Not sure how or why but it works now

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can only change the port number of similar kind.search here
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers